# How i compare a IQueryable to something?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i want compare IQueryable to "[ ]" because is what API returns when is null

i have this

```
var query = from Consumer in context.Consumer
 from Patient in context.Patient
 where Consumer.id == iduser
 where Patient.PATHOLOGY_id == idpato
 where Consumer.id == Patient.CONSUMER_id_patient
 select Patient;

if ( query == "[]")
{
    return  this.RedirectToAction(nameof(this.PatientCreate));
}
else
{
    return Ok(query.ToString());
}
```

but i can't use operattorers on IQueryable, how i do that?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? This code kinda does not make sense. Are you trying to fetch patient from Db and if it does not exist redirect to creation of a new one?

Comment: What does `[]` even mean? Do you mean `query.Any()` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will "return" a collection of `Patient` objects (technically a lazy-loaded iterator, but functionally a collection), so it will not ever "equal" the string "[]". If the response from the data source is an empty JSON list, then `query` will most likely represent an empty collection, so you could try:

```
if(!query.Any())
 // no results
else
 // do something
```

But note that `query.Any()` will execute the query, and iterating the results in the view will *also* run the query, so you probably want to execute the query only once - `ToList()` is an effective way to do that:

```
var query = (from Consumer in context.Consumer
 from Patient in context.Patient
 where Consumer.id == iduser
 where Patient.PATHOLOGY_id == idpato
 where Consumer.id == Patient.CONSUMER_id_patient
 select Patient).ToList();
```

That way, you've already collected the results, so `Any()` will not

Finally, `query.ToString()` will not do what you probably think it does - I presume that you just want to pass the collection to the view, so you probably just want

```
return Ok(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need something like this:

```
var query = from Consumer in context.Consumer
 from Patient in context.Patient
 where Consumer.id == iduser
 where Patient.PATHOLOGY_id == idpato
 where Consumer.id == Patient.CONSUMER_id_patient
 select Patient;
var result = query.ToArray();
if ( !result.Any())
{
    return  this.RedirectToAction(nameof(this.PatientCreate));
}
else
{
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from Consumer in context.Consumer
 from Patient in context.Patient
 where Consumer.id == iduser
 where Patient.PATHOLOGY_id == idpato
 where Consumer.id == Patient.CONSUMER_id_patient
 select Patient;

if ( query.Count() == 0 )
{
    return  this.RedirectToAction(nameof(this.PatientCreate));
}
else
{
    return Ok(query.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation on what need to change in order to learn from the answer.

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than the existing answers?